# Resource manager exception, no solution seems to work

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, resourcemanager

Trying to use resource manager to get a string from a resource in a project, I keep getting the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type system.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

So I decided to create a console app to test it and I am still getting the same problem, I have tried various solutions and always get the same exception.

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resource1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            string someString = rm.GetString("test");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My Resources file]
[image: My solution structure]

Comment: Reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx), you should be able to access the resource via: `string someString = ConsoleApplication1.Resources.Resource1.test;`

Comment: Had to make a small edit, for some reason the Resources part wouldn't appear. But thank you that solves my problem!  Although I would love to know why the other solution wouldn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace for your resource, try

```
ResourceManager rm = 
   new ResourceManager("ConsoleApplication1.Resource1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I prefer to use type information like this

```
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(ConsoleApplication1.Resource1));
```

Here's a great [write-up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx) about using ResourceManager.

Comment: That's exactly what it was then, thank you for the link and solution I plan on making good use of resourcemanager in my project so it will be a great help.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fully qualify the resource name:

```
ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("ConsoleApplication1.Resource1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Quantic worked for me, thanks Quantic!

```
string someString = ConsoleApplication1.Resources.Resource1.test;
```